# how prevent laravel's jobs run at the same time

Tags: laravel

I have a job as below:

```
class ProcessActions implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable;
    use InteractsWithQueue;
    use Queueable;
    use SerializesModels;

    protected $user_id;

    public $uniqueFor = 4;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @param mixed $action_id
     */
    public function __construct($user_id)
    {
        $this->user_id = $user_id;
    }

    public function uniqueId()
    {
        return $this->user_id;
    }

    /**
     * Handle a job failure.
     */
    public function failed()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        Log::debug('');
        Log::debug('Started Time: '.date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));


            try {
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Log::critical('Error occurred.');
                Log::critical($e);
                

                // make the job failed
                $this->job->fail($e);
            }
    }

    public function middleware()
    {
        return [(new WithoutOverlapping($this->user_id))->releaseAfter(4)->expireAfter(4)];
    }
}
```

How I should prevent jobs run at the same time? unique and WithoutOverlapping didn't work and I have jobs that run at the same time.

Actually I want jobs with same user_id run by 4 second delay.

Also as I checked jobs'available_at and time that I logged in handle have some seconds difference.

Comment: maybe you can use sleep(5) at the end of every job for a 5second delay

Comment: You might consider https://github.com/spatie/laravel-rate-limited-job-middleware.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ratelimiting feature in laravel

You can read more about here - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#rate-limiting -

In your job class inside handle method add this code -Make sure `key` is a unique value,Here is a sample code

Basically it limit the worker to process one job for a user at a given time.see uuid,next job will be processed 4 sec after.

```
$uuid='process_action_'.$user_id;
Redis::funnel($uuid)->limit(1)->then(function () {
    //job logic
}, function () {
    
    //reattempt the job after 4 seconds
    return $this->release(4);
});
```